# Long build times for Criterion cargo bench but not cargo build --release with large type

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo, build-time, rust-criterion

While working on a [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter in Rust, I noticed that `cargo bench` takes an incredibly long time to build a Criterion bench when the Benchmark contains a large type.

As part of my Brainfuck implementation, I define a structure with a very large array to act as the interpreters memory. When I compile with `cargo build --release`, my crate builds in a handful of seconds, but when I run `cargo bench` the build takes upwards of 6 minutes! I eventually realized this has something to do with the very large array in my type definition (`[u8; 30_000]`). I figured I could make the type smaller via indirection, so I changed my type into a `Box<[u8; 30_000]>` which did reduce my build times significantly for the benchmark.

**My question is: why does `cargo bench` take so much longer to build than `cargo build --release` without `Box<>`, shouldn't they both be using the same optimization level? Why doesn't `cargo build --release` take just as long without `Box<>`?**

Is this potentially a bug with Criterion?

I confirmed via `cargo bench --no-run --timings` nearly all of the time goes the building the bench itself. I also made a minimal reproducible example:

```
cargo --version
> cargo 1.64.0 (387270bc7 2022-09-16)
```

### cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "large-type"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.4.0"

[[bench]]
name = "my_benches"
harness = false
```

### lib.rs

```rust
pub struct MyType {
    data: [u8; 30_000],
}

impl MyType {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        MyType { data: [0; 30_000] }
    }
}
```

### benches/my_benches.rs

```rust
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use large_type::MyType;

pub fn my_test(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("my test", |b| b.iter(|| black_box(MyType::new())));
}

criterion_group!(benches, my_test);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

### Clean release build

```
$ cargo build --release
   Compiling large-type v0.1.0 (C:\Users\myuser\large-type)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.22s
```

### Clean bench build

```
$ cargo bench --no-run
...
...
Compiling large-type v0.1.0 (C:\Users\myuser\large-type)
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in **3m 46s**
```

About 15 seconds go to compiling Criterion dependencies and my library, the remainder goes to `Executable benches\my_benches.rs`.

Lastly, when I do change `[u8; 30_000]` to `Box<[u8; 30_000]>`, both `cargo build --release` and `cargo bench --no-run` complete in a very reasonable about of time. Any ideas?

edit: I guess boxing is an appropriate solution, but I want to avoid the performance hit if possible and understand why there would be a difference between the 2 builds.

Comment: Any solution you got?

Comment: @MetehanYıldırım nothing yet beyond boxing/using a vec, but nothing where the array is kept on the stack.

Comment: Maybe it takes so long because criterion does loop unrolling, and having it on the stack creates a massive stack frame? Just taking wild shots into the blue, though :/

Comment: @Rafael Why do you **have** to keep the array on the stack? For not being intrusive, I would rather modify the benchmark: `c.bench_function("my test", |b| b.iter(|| black_box(Box::new(MyType::new()))));`. Does that improve compile time?

Comment: Looks like OP raised an issue with the criterion project: https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs/issues/626

Answer (score 0):

The `cargo build` command that you posted will not build benchmarks.

```
# Does not build benchmarks
cargo build --release
```

If you want to build the benchmarks with `cargo build` you need to use `--all-targets` (or `--benches`)

```
cargo build --release --all-targets
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvote so I will attempt to clarify.  This issue has nothing to do with criterion.  Yes, building with a stack array instead of a box is much slower but I get the exact same slow time with `cargo build --release --benches` that I do with `cargo bench --no-run`.  In other words, this is purely a rust compiler issue and not a criterion issue.